# ORDER BY multiple values in specific order elastic search

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, e-commerce, graph-algorithm, elasticsearch-5

I have following elastic search doc structure, with customer type's student,teacher,professional i want my search result in student,teacher,professional order, that is in search result  all student's followed by all teacher's followed by all ,professional's.

```
{ "_index": "customer", "_type": "info", "_id": "AWC1xn90RETWF5jlQtczjt", "_version": 1, "_score": 1, "_source": { "name": "name1", "type":"student" } }

{ "_index": "customer", "_type": "info", "_id": "AWC1xnRE23TWF5jlQtczjt", "_version": 1, "_score": 1, "_source": { "name": "name4", "type":"teacher" } }

{ "_index": "customer", "_type": "info", "_id": "AWC1xnRETWF545jlQtczjt", "_version": 1, "_score": 1, "_source": { "name": "name3", "type":"professional" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fix this by assigning numeric value to each type at index time.
So student=0,teacher=1,professional=2 and call it something like type_id and order by that.

However, if there no such option, you can use script fields

```
sort: [
  {
    _script: {
      type: 'number',
      script: {
        lang: 'painless',
        inline: 'switch(doc['type'].value){ case "student" return 0; case "teacher" return 1; case "professional" default return -1}',
      },
      order: 'desc',
    },
  }
]
```

Comment: Sir your solution is pretty promising,is there any other approach possibly?